# Certificates in Iceweasel

Tags: linux, certificate, iceweasel

I'm trying to make a backup of a certificate which is imported to iceweasel. So i#m following the steps Edit->Prereferences->Advanced->Encryption->View Certificates. Then I choose my certificate, and go to backup. Sholud be a file with .p12 ending; I'm saving it in my home directory, but somehow, althougn there is no error popping up, it does not save it.

Would be happy about solutions!

Comment: Suggest saving to another location, possibly the Desktop?